# Remove white grid lines when zoomed in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel-grid

I'm working on a game with lots of precise pixel artwork, and I need to be zoomed in on my work 24/7. Recently I switched to a Mac computer and this version of Photoshop automatically creates an atomically thick grid when you zoom in too close. This is a huge problem.

I've looked in the Preferences but I just can't find anything that will turn it off. I remember being able to do this before, but I don't actually remember how. It might not look like a huge problem, but believe me when I say that it is. Please help me!

[image: The Stupid Grid]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uncheck **"View -> Show -> Pixel Grid"** and "surprise", no pixel grid.

[image: pixel grid]

;)

Comment: Wow, thanks! Don't you ever get the feeling that Adobe is really unorganized? (rhetorical)

Comment: Yes, I think there are many usability problems in the interface and several flaws in the tools of Adobe programs, in particular in Illustrator. A great program, but nothing practical. Corel and Inkscape are much better and more practical to draw, and the Affinity Designer is exceptionally better, to design and imitate natural media.